# How to add class in body or in category-view div if current category don't have image

Tags: category, category-page

How to add any class in body or category-view div on category page if current category don't have image assigned.

Having following top container part in the `catalog_category_view.xml` file.

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: So You want to add class to body if category has no image ?

Comment: yes within body or next to `category-view` class

Answer (score 1):

Override Image.phtml file in your theme.

File Path: 
/app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/image.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
?>
<?php

$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$_imgHtml = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" title="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" class="image" /></div>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
} else {
    ?>
    <script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
       $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('body').addClass('newClass');
        });
    });
</script>


  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks apart from script any other way to call this.

Comment: You can add class like,
In your Layout File :
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>

But you need condition based add class, So i think this is the only way.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good trick to be able to hide some bundle template elements